# NestJS TypeORM Unit Tests mocking getConnection.transaction

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, nestjs, typeorm

I'm writing UT's for the NestJS application.
I'm having issues mocking or even testing the logic of the transaction internal function.

This is a piece of code from the service which gets a connection and starts interacting with the DB using transactionEntityManager.

I wish to test the internal logic of a function like in this example (I have several cases like this).

```js
import { getConnection } from 'typeorm';
@Injectable()
export class UsersService {

    async getUsers(user: User): Promise<{ users: User[], organizations: MinimalOrg[] }> {
        const result: { users: User[], organizations: MinimalOrg[] } = { users: [], organizations: [] };
        // getConnection() is imported from 'typeorm'
        await getConnection().transaction(async (transactionEntityManager) => {
            if (!user || !Utils.isAdmin(user)) {
                throw new UnauthorizedException('You have no permission');
            }

            result.users = await transactionEntityManager
                .createQueryBuilder(User, 'user')
                .leftJoin('user.image', 'image')
                .leftJoin('user.organization', 'organization')
                .select([
                    'user.id',
                    'user.email',
                ])
                .addSelect(['organization.id', 'organization.name'])
                .addSelect(['image.id', 'image.fileName'])
                .getMany();

            result.organizations = (await transactionEntityManager
                .createQueryBuilder(Organization, 'org')
                .select(['org.id', 'org.name'])
                .getMany()) as MinimalOrg[];
        });
        return result;
    }
}
```

I have already tried to use at the Unit tests this approach but I wasn't been able to make it work.

```js
jest.mock('typeorm',()=>({
    transaction:jest.fn()
}));
```

Any help will be really appreciated

Comment: It would be easier to answer if this question had more focus; maybe pick one test that you're trying to write and edit the question to just ask about that?

Comment: At first glance, you're mocking `transaction` from typeorm, whereas you're only importing `getConnection` in the code.

Comment: At the very least, if you want to mock the transaction, you need something like: `({ getConnection: () => ({ transaction: jest.fn() }) })` in your jest.mock

Comment: About the focus: How can I access even the simplest line `if (!user || !Utils.isAdmin(user)) {` if I mock the `geConnection().transaction(` 
And how to mock global functions like `getConnection()` to achieve this?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why use `getConnection()` from `typeorm` and not `@InjectConnection()` from `@nestjs/typeorm` to inject the connection and be able to mock it in the (nest) convention?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, @JayMcDoniel can be helpful to mock the connection itself but how can I test the transaction method of the connection? Like this line `if (!user || !Utils.isAdmin(user)) {`

Comment: @PiniCheyni I updated my answer, doesn't it solve the problem?

Comment: @omidh no because it mocks the whole transaction but I want to test the contents of the transaction input method, I want to test the 9'th line `if (!user || !Utils.isAdmin(user)) {` but if I mock the whole transaction then It becomes impossible

Comment: @PiniCheyni Your code is executed inside the transaction body, How do you want to test it without mocking transaction first? What do you mean "it becomes impossible"?

Comment: @PiniCheyni Did you solve it? I want to know the solution

Comment: @omidh Yes, I have added my solution here on March 13th.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

After several days of investigation and feedback from you I came to this solution with the following steps:

1. install sqlite3 in devDependencies (will be used in-memory DB just
   for the connection).
2. Injected to the constructor of the service
   `@InjectConnection() private readonly connection: Connection`.
3. decorate the method with @Transaction() and add a new parameter of the service method `@TransactionManager() _manager?`.

The service method looks now like this:

```js
    @Transaction()
    async getUsers(
        user: User,
        @TransactionManager() _manager?
    ): Promise<{ users: User[], organizations: MinimalOrg[] }> {
        const result: { users: User[], organizations: MinimalOrg[] } = { users: [], organizations: [] };
        const transactionEntityManager = this.connection.manager;
        if (!user || !Utils.isAdmin(user)) {
            throw new UnauthorizedException('You have no permission');
        }
        result.users = await transactionEntityManager
            .createQueryBuilder(User, 'user')
            .leftJoin('user.image', 'image')
            .leftJoin('user.organization', 'organization')
            .select([
                'user.id',
                'user.email',
            ])
            .addSelect(['organization.id', 'organization.name'])
            .addSelect(['image.id', 'image.fileName'])
            .getMany();
        result.organizations = (await transactionEntityManager
            .createQueryBuilder(Organization, 'org')
            .select(['org.id', 'org.name'])
            .getMany()) as MinimalOrg[];
        return result;
    }
```

At the spec file, it importent to set the imports with the database configurations as shown below:

```js
/* eslint-disable import/no-extraneous-dependencies */
import { Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Test } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { getConnectionToken, TypeOrmModule, } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { UserRole } from 'gn-models';
import { ConnectionOptions, getConnection } from 'typeorm';

import { User } from '../models/user.entity';
import { UsersService } from './users.service';

// #region Mock
const createQueryBuilder: any = {
    createQueryBuilder: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => createQueryBuilder),
    select: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => createQueryBuilder),
    andWhere: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => createQueryBuilder),
    addSelect: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => createQueryBuilder),
    leftJoinAndSelect: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => createQueryBuilder),
    innerJoin: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => createQueryBuilder),
    leftJoin: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => createQueryBuilder),
    groupBy: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => createQueryBuilder),
    where: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => createQueryBuilder),
    findOne: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => null),
    save: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => null),
    getOne: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => null),
    getMany: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => null),
    getRawMany: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => null)
}
// #endregion

describe('UsersService', () => {
    let srv: UsersService;
    beforeEach(async () => {
        const moduleRef = await Test.createTestingModule({
            imports: [
                TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
                    type: "sqlite",
                    database: ":memory:",
                    dropSchema: true,
                    synchronize: true,
                    logging: false,
                    name: 'default'
                } as ConnectionOptions)
            ],
            providers: [
                UsersService,
                {
                    provide: getConnectionToken(),
                    useValue: {
                        manager: createQueryBuilder,
                        ...createQueryBuilder
                    }
                },
            ],
        }).compile();

        // Disable log error prints 
        jest.spyOn(Logger, 'error').mockReturnValue();

        srv = moduleRef.get<UsersService>(UsersService);
    });

    afterEach(async () => {
        jest.clearAllMocks();
        await getConnection().close();
    });


    it('should test getUsers', async () => {
        const userRecord = { rdp: '1', userName: 'aaa', roles: [UserRole.SuperAdmin] } as User;

        const res = await srv.getUsers(userRecord);
        expect(res).toBeTruthy();
        expect(res).toEqual({ users: null, organizations: null })
    });

    it('should test getUsers if the user is not admin', async () => {
        const userRecord = { rdp: '1', userName: 'aaa', roles: [] } as User;
        expect.assertions(1);
        const res = srv.getUsers(userRecord);
        await expect(res).rejects
            .toThrowError('You have no permission');
    });
});
```

Notice the **manager** is set at **beforeEach** for the connection allows mocking the entity-manager in tests and still use it at the service method `const transactionEntityManager = this.connection.manager;`.

I have set the `await getConnection().close();` at **afterEach** so each test will run independently of each other. If the connection is already open jest will fail to run other tests with the same connection name (default).

I'm not saying that this is the best solution but it worked for me after investing a lot of time and effort in making this work.

I hope it helps you to write UT for your projects!

Answer (score 2):

You need to mock `getConnection()` first before mocking `transction()` itself.

```js
const queryBuilderMock = {
  leftJoin: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
  select: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
  addSelect: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
  getMany: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(['your_mocked_object_here']),
};

const entityManagerMock = { createQueryBuilder: () => queryBuilderMock };
const transactionMock = jest.fn(async passedFunction => await passedFunction(entityManagerMock));

jest.mock('typeorm', () => ({
  getConnection: () => ({ transaction: transactionMock })
}));
```

Also don't forget to clean/reset needed mocks before each test.

```js
  beforeEach(async () => {
    queryBuilderMock.addSelect.mockClear();
    queryBuilderMock.select.mockClear();
    queryBuilderMock.getMany.mockClear();
    queryBuilderMock.leftJoin.mockClear();
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [UsersService],
    }).compile();

    service = module.get<UsersService>(UsersService);
  });
```

If you want to test `(!user || !Utils.isAdmin(user))` exception line you can try this:

```js
it('should throw exception if passed user is null', async () => {
  await expect(service.getUsers(null as any)).rejects.toThrow(UnauthorizedException);
});
```